# Django admin on change event

Tags: django, django-admin

I am using Django 1.7 and have a model admin with 2 textboxes. How can I listen to onchange event on the first one and update the second one?

Comment: Take a look at [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Comment: I expect there are some places to config it using python instead of overriding its template and using jquery.

Comment: Okay maybe I misunderstood. You want to update the second textbox **immediately** when text is entered into the first textbox or after the save button is pressed?

Comment: Immediately, like onchange event in jquery :)

Comment: Then I'm afraid there's no way doing this with python/django, because only when you **save** your model in the admin the entered data is transferred to your server. So you'll have to use something client-side (based on javascript) to listen for change events. I'd suggest jQuery or any other javascript library to achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

define a form in admin.py

```
class YourForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Media:
       js = ('//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js', 'js/custom_admin_validate.js')

class YourAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   form = YourForm
   #..
```

and now, in `custom_admin_validate.js` you can play with jquery in your adminpage.

please  note, you may also want `clean` method of form to validate further in backend..